# Stub dynamic finder using spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I need help with a **Spock** test.
I am trying to stub a Domain Object's dynamic finder (`findById`).
I can't use code like:

```
ObjectDomain.metaClass.static.findById = { -> new ObjectDomain()}
```

because I use the `findsById` method in other part of the test and if I use that I get false positives.

anybody knows the best way to stub dynamic finders using Spock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `findById`? Unless you're using Hibernate filters you should be using `get()` - it's the same query but cached more intelligently

Comment: Hi @BurtBeckwith, I am using this code: `def ticket = Entrada.findById(ticketId, [fetch: ['tipo': 'join', 'tipo.evento': 'join'], readOnly:true])` and I would like to stub calls to findById

Comment: Right, to specify fetch or lazy:false you need a finder. Note that if you were only using readOnly:true the call would be equivalent to `Entrada.read(ticketId)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument number and types have to match between your metaclass method and the real method. You added a no-arg `findById()` method but you're calling an overloaded method with an id and a Map. So you'd need to change the closure args to match:

```
ObjectDomain.metaClass.static.findById = { id, Map args -> new ObjectDomain()}
```

Comment: hi @BurtBeckwith, First of all, thanks for taking the time to answer my question.
My problem is that I don't want that all my **feature methods** have this behaviour, I would like to in some cases return an Object Domain and in others cases a null. Is possible stubbing this behaviour  not using the **metaclass**?

Comment: Sure - inspect the value if the id and/or the contents of the map, and return the instances or null based on how the method is called

Comment: What about using the [ConfineMetaClassChanges](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/spock-confinemetaclasschanges-annotation-made-writing-grails-unit-test-easier/) annotation in Spock? I've never used it myself yet, but I've read about it several times and it seems it can be applied to individual methods.

Comment: Grails cleans up the metaclass between tests for you. There's a metaclass change event that you can listen for and register a helper to cache the initial metaclass and restore it after the test runs, and that is done in unit and integration tests.

Comment: Both solutions works properly, Thank you very much I really appreciate your help.